# Covariance of linear models with Second Order Assumptions

Tags: linear-model, covariance

I have been studying linear models recently and I'm confused why $cov(Y) = cov(\epsilon)$ holds for $Y = X\beta + \epsilon$. This was just kinda assumed in my course notes

[image]

I was looking at this section specifically

Comment: Welcome to CV, Andrew. This is not true unless $\beta=0$ or $X$ is constant. Perhaps you mean the covariance *conditional* on $X$?

Comment: @utobi That doesn't follow.  With orthogonality, $\operatorname{Cov}(Y) = \beta^\prime \operatorname{Cov}(X)\beta + \operatorname{Cov}(\epsilon) \ne \operatorname{Cov}(\epsilon)$ unless the special conditions I mentioned in my first comment hold.

Comment: @whuber I added a screenshot of the course note that I was looking at, I don't think $\beta = 0$ and $X$ is also not necessarily constant

Comment: If you don't think so, then why not?  Are you working with a particular example or dataset?  The formulas in the image never examine the covariance of $Y$ alone: therein lies the resolution of your problem.  You seem implicitly to suppose that when $A^\prime B A = C$ then $B=C$ for matrices, but that's not the case.